# Publishing to bluemix from eclipse results in stack overflow and forces the eclipse workbench to shutdown

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools, ibm-cloud-plugin

Whenever I try to publish to IBM bluemix from eclipse using IBM bluemix tools, I stuck in this error, stack overflow and the workbench quickly run out of memoery. can anyone help?

```
An internal error occurred during: "Publishing to IBM Bluemix...".
java.lang.StackOverflowError


eclipse.buildId=4.7.3.M20180330-0640
java.version=1.8.0_151
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.core.jobs
Error
Sun Jun 17 23:53:28 BST 2018
An internal error occurred during: "Publishing to IBM Bluemix...".

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.ibm.st.common.core.internal.PublishUnit.getDeltaKinds(PublishUnit.java:123)
    at com.ibm.st.common.core.internal.PublishUnit.getDeltaKinds(PublishUnit.java:127)
    at com.ibm.st.common.core.internal.PublishUnit.getDeltaKinds(PublishUnit.java:127)
    at com.ibm.st.common.core.internal.PublishUnit.getDeltaKinds(PublishUnit.java:127)
    at com.ibm.st.common.core.internal.PublishUnit.getDeltaKinds(PublishUnit.java:127)
    at com.ibm.st.common.core.internal.PublishUnit.getDeltaKinds(PublishUnit.java:127)
    at com.ibm.st.common.core.internal.PublishUnit.getDeltaKinds(PublishUnit.java:127)
    at com.ibm.st.common.core.internal.PublishUnit.getDeltaKinds(PublishUnit.java:127)
    at com.ibm.st.common.core.internal.PublishUnit.getDeltaKinds(PublishUnit.java:127)
    at com.ibm.st.common.core.internal.PublishUnit.getDeltaKinds(PublishUnit.java:127)
    at com.ibm.st.common.core.internal.PublishUnit.getDeltaKinds(PublishUnit.java:127)
    at com.ibm.st.common.core.internal.PublishUnit.getDeltaKinds(PublishUnit.java:127)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution. it turns out that eclipse has trouble storing the bluemix password and it failed unexpectedly during connection and stuck in a loop.

Check your eclipse secure storage (Preference>Security>Secure Storage) and make sure eclipse can access it and store passwords.